# problems to run rails s on Rails 4 :S

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im trying to run s on my project in Rails 4.2.2 
but i get a unexpected error :S  
Someone know the reason of the error? 
Thanks in advance
This is my logs .................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
➜  backend-ror git:(dev) ✗ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 4.2.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Expected string default value for '--jbuilder'; got true (boolean)
Expected string default value for '--serializer'; got true (boolean)
Exiting
/Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load': /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/app/controllers/application_controller.rb:39: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/inherited_resources-1.9.0/app/controllers/inherited_resources/base.rb:11:in `<module:InheritedResources>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/inherited_resources-1.9.0/app/controllers/inherited_resources/base.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `block in load_file'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load_file'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activeadmin-1.4.3/lib/active_admin/base_controller/authorization.rb:2:in `<module:ActiveAdmin>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activeadmin-1.4.3/lib/active_admin/base_controller/authorization.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activeadmin-1.4.3/lib/active_admin/base_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activeadmin-1.4.3/lib/active_admin/application.rb:166:in `controllers_for_filters'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activeadmin-1.4.3/lib/active_admin/application.rb:159:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Application>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activeadmin-1.4.3/lib/active_admin.rb:69:in `setup'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/config/initializers/active_admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/server.rb:300:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/server.rb:209:in `app'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/server.rb:337:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/client.rb:28:in `run'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/vendor/cache/ruby/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.5.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /Users/Cristopheer96/code/Cristopheer96/Guudjob/backend-ror/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from ./bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from ./bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
➜  backend-ror git:(dev) ✗
```

Comment: Can you post your application_controller.rb code in the question?

Comment: I can't believe it, there was a syntax error at line 39 "application_controller.rb", I feel very embarrassed, but your comment helped me focus on that line.
Should I delete the post?